# Авторизация с помощью ключа

Tags: php, java, spring, api, fetch

Хочу сделать авторизацию с помощью ключа, но появилось много вопрос.
**[По идеии]** 
На первом сайте у меня авторизация нормальная через Login,Password, авторизация храниться в сессии.
При заходе на второй сайт отправляется запрос на сервер второго сайта, который в следствии отправляет запрос на первый. 
***Сайт #2 > Сервер #2 > Сервер #1*** (Да я знаю что можно без такой лабуды, а сразу ***Сайт #2 > Сервер #1***)

Но как узнать что запрос именно отправлен пользователем который авторизовался.
Знаю что можно хранить ключ в куках ***auth_key=ключ в md5*** или ***auth_key=ключ в base64(логин и пароль(пароль в md5))***, но кражу ни отменял(не знаю как определить владельца, даже если он уже авторизован на первом сайте, или если куки с ключом был украден).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139702/discussion-on-question-by-bcd----).

Comment: @Grundy комон, мы же не закончили даже разговор, а я теперь уведомления не получу

Comment: заходи в чат, там тоже уведомления есть

Comment: @Grundy они там 1) опаздывают 2) и работают только если есть упоминание меня. А тут уведомлене моментальное и для беседы 2 челов не надо упоминаний.

Comment: Да в принципе можно было закрывать вопрос :)